# Form Recordset in Access 2007 Returning no data

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm building a form in access that has a several sub-forms in a tab control  The sub-forms are working fine, but when I set the parent form's Record Source property and bind a few Text Boxes to the data, I find that a null recordset has been returned.

I've tried this with several different queries (each of which works in a separate query designer) to no avail.  I've also tried binding the form to a Table directly and a null recordset is still returned.

I've checked the filters and they are turned off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Text Boxes that are bound to data are Locked and Disabled then the query will return a null dataset by default.

The form's 'Data Entry' property also needs to be set to false.  Setting it to true will make the form for data entry only. This prevents any data that might be returned by the background dataset from appearing when the form loads.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. How are you pulling the record set out (can you provided a code example)? What happens if you have one Text Box that is not Locked & Disabled? Do you loose the whole record set, or just the fields that are Locked and Disabled?

Comment: I'm just reporting what worked (I'm only guessing as to why).

I didn't include a code example because this is all done in the Access 2007 form designer GUI.  No code to be found.  The query (if I was actually using a query) would read something like this:
    SELECT * FROM Table;
Not a whole lot there.

And when I bind a field to a locked and disabled Text Box I lose the whole recordset, not just a few fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing a Requery on your parent form:

```
Me.RecordSource = "someQuery"
Me.Requery
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Can you unlock and/or enable the fields before setting the data source?

Comment: I could and then lock them in the On Load method, but the data mainly for reference anyway.  I don't do any additions from the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the relationships in your tables especially if you used the auto "look-up" option to create a relationship. 
Open your tables in design view and check if your foreign keys(FK) are indexed appropriately or not (under field properties).
If they are indexed, ensure you have the correct type of index for that particular field. Example; TABLE A with following columns PatientID(PK), PatientName  and  TABLE B with columns ID, PatientHeight, PatientWeight, PatientBP, PatientID(FK)
For such Table B, if you have the "PatientID(FK) indexed with "duplication OK", you will get RecordSet error when using those fields related to this table in the form especially if the form JOINS fields from multiple tables.
In summary, try checking the indexing of your fields especially if they correspond to their type of relationship

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer is a little difficult to understand, please try to increase readability using interpunction, spacing between paragraphs, and code formatting